# Meeting a condition before allowing level to change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a coin to my game. If the coin isn't touched then the level won't be able to switch until the player touches the coin. My scripts are trying to set a value in a variable then when the value increases to 1 then it allowed the level to change.

How do I fix my scripts?

Coin script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject destroyCoin;
    public static int coinWorth = 0;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == "Coin")
        {
            Destroy(destroyCoin);
            coinWorth = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

GameManager script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager4 : MonoBehaviour {

    Coin coinValue = GetComponent<Coin>().coinWorth;

    void Update ()
    {
        coinValue = Coin.coinWorth;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other){
        if (other.transform.tag == "Complete" && coinValue > 0) {
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone has any questions on what i'm asking feel free to ask

Answer (score 3):

It might be simpler to have the Coin send its value directly to the GameManager upon collision.

Should your coin perhaps be searching for a 'Player' tag rather than a 'Coin' tag (I am assuming that the Coin.cs script will be attached to a coin object which will have the 'Coin' tag).

So in you scripts it would look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour {
    // Drag your Game Manager object into this slot in the inspector
    public GameObject GameManager;
    public static int coinWorth = 1;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        // If the coin is collided into by an object tagged 'player'
        if (other.transform.tag == "Player")
       {
            // retrieve the gamemanager component from the game manager object and increment its value
            GameManager.GetComponent<GameManager4>().coinValue++;
            // Destroy this instance of the coin
            Destroy(gameObject);
       }
    }
}
```

Then your second script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager4 : MonoBehaviour {
    // Declare the coinValue as a public int so that it can be accessed from the coin script directly
    public int coinValue = 0;

    void Update ()
    {
        // This shouldn't be necessary to check on each update cycle
        //coinValue = Coin.coinWorth;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other){
        if (other.transform.tag == "Complete" && coinValue > 0) {
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course if you are instancing the coin from a prefab then you would need to do this differently as you wouldn't be able to drag the game menager in the inspector. If thats the case then it might be worthwhile to use a singleton class for the game manager. Let me know if that is the case and I'll show you how to do this :)

Comment: It doesn't allow me to drag a script into a game object

Comment: I just read over what you said, I have no idea how todo that. If you could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sure thing, 
 
so you have a coin object with the coin script on it. 
and then you have a game manager object with the gamemanager script on it.

if you look at the inspector for the coin object, there will be a space called Game Manager. this space is where you drag and drop the Game Manager object from your scene hierarchy.

Try that with the script i gave you (not that your character will need to be tagged 'Player' and the coin will need to have a collider on it.

Try that and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Both scripts have been put on the player. What do I do?

Comment: Wait actually, If I change the tag to 'Player' and attached it to coin, and leave the Gamemanager on the Player then it works. Thanks for all the help, is there anyway I can contact you if I ever need help again you're very helpful!

Comment: Great I'm glad you got it working :) If you have other questions, please feel free to post them and I will try to help out where I can, best of luck!